# Best Visual Studio 2008 Debugging Tutorial?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Is there a good debugging tutorial for VS 2008 (C#, more precisely)? I have found a good deal of resources on the web, but they are still lacking a comprehensive, step by step, approach. Would you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These aren't specific to Visual Studio 2008, but their information is certainly still valid when developing with VS2008.

To get you started immediately, check out [Tess Ferrandez](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/), she has great "getting started" set of labs. These will probably tackle your step by step needs and are scenario based.

When your looking for more detail, pick up a copy of John Robbins ["Debugging Microsoft .NET 2.0 Applications"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735622027).  John covers quite a bit of Visual Studio IDE kung fu which may be precisely what your looking for.

If thats not quite enough, and you don't mind your brain melting, you can pick up a copy of ["Microsoft Windows Internals (4th Edition): Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, and Windows 2000"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619174) by Mark Russinovich and David Solomon.  Looks like they have an updated version releasing in June 2009.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at these [series](http://blogs.msdn.com/brunoterkaly/archive/2009/02/08/the-art-of-debugging-a-developer-s-best-friend-intro-lesson-1.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

MSDN has a comprehensive resource for application development in Visual Studio - [Building, Debugging, and Testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8k88a0k.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are several books available that cover more advanced uses of Visual Studio and .NET debugging. Some of these include coverage of WinDBG for more advanced scenarios.

One I've learnt a lot from is "Debugging Microsoft® .NET 2.0 Applications" by John Robbins (MS Press).