# Updating PDB files without rebuilding

Tags: debugging, pdb-files

Is there a way to update the PDB file with the new source location ? I have a project which links to some libraries which are built on another machine and are debug build with the PDB file. I cannot put a breakpoint in the files which are compiled in the libs. These libs take more than 4 hours to build so I dont want to buid them on my machine. Is there a way where i can make the compiler use the new source paths. I am using VS 2005 pro c++.

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the `.pdb` files to adjust to where you have your source, you should be able to make the debugger see the new source path. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdks6de6.aspx) for instructions on doing this in Visual Studio, and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc266395.aspx) for instructions on doing this in WinDbg.

Another this StackOverflow question: [Best Visual Studio 2008 Debugging Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788807/best-visual-studio-2008-debugging-tutorial).

Comment: Hi Jared,

Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution, but I still cannot add a break point. Can you point me to some article or resource where I can get a detailed working of the debugger, as how it uses the pdb file. Do you have any other suggestions ?
Thanks again for your help.

Cheers Amit

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to another StackOverflow question that has lots of links to tutorials. I've seen what you're experiencing, but can't remember what I did to "convince" it where the source was. One strategy might be to set a breakpoint on a function, which you can specify by name instead of clicking on the source.

Answer (score 1):

Is the debugger picking up the `.pdb` files from the wrong location?  Do you have a copy of the `.pdb` files that match the **binaries** (i.e. `.exe`, `.dll`) that you are executing?  Keep in mind that the `.pdb` files can only be used if they were created at the same time as the *exact* **binaries** you are executing.

Try the following:

1. Rename the (stale) `.pdb` file that the debugger *wants* to load, so the debugger will no longer try to pick it up.
2. Go to `Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols` and add the symbol file (`.pdb`) location to the list.
3. If the debugger is already attached, right click on the module in the "Modules" list and click "Load symbols".  This will re-load the symbols from the path you entered.

Also, if you *know* the code is exactly the same, but your `.pdb` file doesn't match the binaries you are using because they were created during different builds, try un-checking the following checkbox:

`Tools->Options->Debugging->Require source files to exactly match the original version`